# Reverse of hg backout

Tags: mercurial

I'm looking for a method like `hg backout`, but in reverse. Specifically, instead of undoing the diffs associated with a given changset, I want to actually apply them on top of an arbitrary revision. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hg transplant` (bundled extension) or `hg graft` (core, since 2.0) do this.